# A Component Outside of the Routes is Being Rendered Twice

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Routes from react-router-dom to have a home page component rendered at one url and a menu component rendered at another url, but on the same page and with the same header and footer, the problem is my code is rendering the header twice and I am not sure why?

this is my render function:

```
render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={ <Home/> }/>
          <Route exact path="/menu" element={ <Menu dishes={ this.state.dishes }/> }/>
          <Route path="*" element={ <Navigate replace to="/home"/> }/>
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I was expecting the header to render only once, when i delete the

```
<Route path="/home" element={ <Home/> }/>
```

line it only renders the header once

here is my headerComponent

```
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <Navbar dark>
                    <div className="container">
                        <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
                    </div>
                </Navbar>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row row-header">
                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                <h1>Ristorante Con Fusion</h1>
                                <p>We Take Inspiration from the Worlds Best Cuisine yada yada yada</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

this is the home component

```
import React from "react";

function Home(props) {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h4>Home</h4>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: It usually means that you've use header and footer in one of the routes as well

Comment: I agree with @Konrad.  You must be rendering some component that is having that header component as child as well.

Comment: @Konrad when I delete the route to <Home/> element the second header goes away, is props passing header on?

Comment: *is props passing header on?* - I don't understand that part

Comment: Show your `Home` component please

Comment: @Konrad, i updated the question to show my HeaderComponent, and my HomeComponent

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in my imports

this is what i had:

```
import Home from './HeaderComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
```